# Tag-like skills in a user profile with a HABTM relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

In the web application I'm building a user has a profile where they can list their skills. I would like the kind of functionality StackOverflow has when making posts, where you can type tags into the tag input and select ones that already exist, and create them if they don't already exist.

At the moment, I've got a select box appearing on the page with with the `id` of the users current skills as values. I'm achieving this by doing:

```
// ProfilesController.php
$skills = $this->Profile->ProfilesSkill->find('list');

// edit.ctp
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Skill', array('value' => $skills)); ?>
```

I've got no idea how to progress further, though. First of all, the `name` field for the skills should be shown instead of their `id`, which I'm confused about because by Cake's convention it will use the `name` field by default, even though it's not. And secondly when I enter my skills into my profile Cake should automatically make all the required entries in the `profiles_skills` table. How can I make that work?

Comment: I suggest breaking this down into smaller questions and giving more detail about the individual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty straight forward, though it's pretty much work.

First you'll need a Tag-System. You could build one on your own (like any habtm-relation), or use a plugin like https://github.com/CakeDC/tags

For the second part, the function is called "Autocomplete". It's basically a ajax call every time you enter a letter in a form field. There are a bunch of tutorials out there, e.g: http://blogfreakz.com/cakephp/cakephp-jquery-autocomplete-tutorial/

Hope this points you in the right direction